# Pass Oracle connection to BIRT report

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, birt

I've created a BIRT report template which uses DB (in my case Oracle DB).
The query is like:

> SELECT SOMETHING, QUANTITY FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMETHING LIKE ?

From Eclipse (for BIRT reports) everything is working. The problem is that I want to create a web service that will do the job.
So I try to pass the connection like:

```
Connection conn = null;
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:name","user","pass");
    } catch (SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException Message: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    task.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnection", conn);
    task.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnectionCloseAfterUse", false);
```

And I get:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Failed to prepare the following query for the data set type (org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.sqbDataSet). 
[SELECT SOMETHING, QUANTITY FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMETHING LIKE ?
]
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaHelperException: The established connection to the data source is not active.
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.Connection.prepareOdaQuery(Connection.java:298)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:197)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.prepareStatement(DataSource.java:302)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.prepare(DataSourceQuery.java:281)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.prepareOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:442)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:341)
... 66 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaHelperException: The established connection to the data source is not active.
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaObject.newOdaException(OdaObject.java:548)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.newQuery(OdaConnection.java:562)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.Connection.prepareOdaQuery(Connection.java:285)
... 71 more
```

All I found on the net is: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360702 but it did not really helped me, I'm not really sure I understand the comments.

Can someone help me with it? Code example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

it seems there is no problem with this code actually. I just used some bugged version of BIRT (4.2.0). After updating to 4.4.1 everything works fine.